# Quicksort with median-of-three not sorting properly?

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

Please explain to me what I am doing wrong in my Quicksort code because the output array is not correctly sorted. It is using the median of three partitioning to select the pivot.

Here is the code:

```
def medianof3(arr, low, high):
  center = (low + high) // 2
  if arr[low] < arr[center]:
    arr[low], arr[center] = arr[center], arr[low]

  if arr[low] < arr[high]:
    arr[low], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[low]

  if arr[center] < arr[high]:
    arr[center], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[center]

  arr[center], arr[high - 1] = arr[high - 1], arr[center]

  return arr[high - 1]


def partition(array, low, high):

    # choose the rightmost element as pivot
    pivot = medianof3(array, low, high)

    # pointer for greater element
    i = low - 1

    # traverse through all elements
    # compare each element with pivot
    for j in range(low, high):
        if array[j] <= pivot:

            # If element smaller than pivot is found
            # swap it with the greater element pointed by i
            i = i + 1

            # Swapping element at i with element at j
            (array[i], array[j]) = (array[j], array[i])

    # Swap the pivot element with the greater element specified by i
    (array[i + 1], array[high - 1]) = (array[high - 1], array[i + 1])

    # Return the position from where partition is done
    return i + 1
 
# function to perform quicksort
 
 
def quickSort(array, low, high):
    if low < high:
 
        # Find pivot element such that
        # element smaller than pivot are on the left
        # element greater than pivot are on the right
        pi = partition(array, low, high)
 
        # Recursive call on the left of pivot
        quickSort(array, low, pi - 1)
 
        # Recursive call on the right of pivot
        quickSort(array, pi + 1, high)
 
 
data = [1, 7, 4, 1, 10, 9, -2]
print("Unsorted Array")
print(data)
 
size = len(data)
 
quickSort(data, 0, size - 1)
 
print('Sorted Array in Ascending Order:')
print(data)
```

Output:

Unsorted Array:
[1, 7, 4, 1, 10, 9, -2]

Sorted Array in Ascending Order:
[1, 1, 7, 4, 9, 10, -2]

Comment: You have some complex logic. It's not working and you don't understand why. So the [next step](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is to write a [unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase). Please update your question. If you've not yet written a test, tell us why. If you have a (failing / red) test, include it with the code.

Comment: Not saying that that's the bug, but: why does you medianof3 function change the array?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have not marked the answer to your previous question as accepted? It received quite a few votes, so... why?

Comment: @trincot that was cus none of them really worked. I should have posted an update to that question tho.thx for reminding me. Edit: I've answered that question. honestly should've done that much earlier but had already answered that on reddit, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is confusion in your code about what represents the rightmost element in a list. Is it at `high` or is it at `high-1`. Both assumptions can be found in your code, and obviously the mix breaks the correct algorithm.

In `medianof3` the first few swaps indicate that `high` is *included* in the sublist, but then the final swap in that function makes a swap with the element at `high-1`... so you end up with a returned pivot that is *not* the rightmost element.

Then in `partition` the loop goes up to -- but excluding -- `high`. This is consistent with the assumption that the pivot sits at `high`. But then there is again a final swap with the element at `high-1`.

Then in `quickSort` the recursive calls use the assumption that the last argument indicates an index that is *included* in the sublist to be sorted.

So all those `high-1` have to be corrected to `high`. Then it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answered all my queries.